# Unable to send "Unauthorized" in http header from Spring Boot filter

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, servlets, spring-boot

I am trying to write an Authentication Filter using `Spring Boot`; wherein I check some cookie, if it is present in request I want to mark the request as authorised if not I want to return `401` header in response to client calling my service.

Below is the line which I am using in my Spring Boot filter:

```
((HttpServletResponse) res).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "User is not authenticated, so can not access IPT service.");
```

Though this line gets executed in my Auth filter when cookie is absent in request; in my client code I do not see header `401` set when checked using `response.headers`

I even tried using:

```
((HttpServletResponse) res).addHeader("401", "Unauthorized!");
return;
```

But, no luck!

Am I doing anything wrong?

EDIT #1:

Adding a client code which deals with request/response:

```
fetch(FETCH_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  credentials: 'include'

}).then(
  function(response) {
    if(response.status == 401) {
      console.log("----->", response);
      alert(response + " Redirect to login page!");
    }
  },
  function() {
    alert("Error!");
});
```

EDIT #2:

When I try to get error message as suggested by Finnbar O'G:

```
response.text().then((text) => { console.log("----->", text); });
```

I get whole HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><title>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</title>
    <style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> User is not authenticated, so can not access IPT service.</p><p><b>Description</b> The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get just the message from server which I have added as second argument of my `sendError` method?

And well, here is my Filter code:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    LOGGER.info("****************** Inside Auth Filter ******************");
    boolean success = process(req); // Checks if auth cookie is set in request

    if (success) {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
        // ((HttpServletResponse) res).addHeader("401", "Unauthorized!");
        ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "User is not authenticated, so can not access IPT service.");
    }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your filters code and filters configs.

Answer (score 1):

response.headers would only contain the HTTP headers which are set, sendError is sending a complete HTTP response which includes, headers, response body and status. response.status would be the 401 error, and response.body would be the message 'User is not authenticated, so can not access IPT service.'. You should check these in your client code.

Edit:

Since you use fetch() you can to access the response body as plain tet with response.text(). This returns a Promise that must be resolved before you can work with the response body: e.g.

```
fetch(FETCH_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  credentials: 'include'

}).then(
  function(response) {
    if(response.status == 401) {
      response.text().then((text) => { console.log("----->", text); });
      alert(response + " Redirect to login page!");
    }
  },
  function() {
    alert("Error!");
});
```

MDN docs on using fetch are a good help for understanding how to work with responses.

Comment: Thanks! I can get error code in response.status as 401. But, I am not able to get message in response.body per say.....

Comment: Can you post the client code which deals with your request and response? You may need to refer to the API reference for the particular response implementation which is generated in your client code. Do you use XHR or fetch perhaps?

Comment: Added in my question, I am using fetch.

Comment: Check my updated answer above so, I think this will get you your response body as text which you can console.log.

Comment: Oops.. it prints whole HTML like as shown in my updated question above

Comment: HttpServletResponse 'sendError()' default behaviour is defined here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int, java.lang.String). `The server defaults to creating the response to look like an HTML-formatted server error page containing the specified message, setting the content type to "text/html"`. Can you post the complete code of your spring boot filter? Or at least the method signature and code relevant to 'res' your response object? Probably using sendError isn't the solution

Comment: Well, Spring boot filter code is pretty simple. Adding the doFilter method in my question above...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using below process:

1. Create a class and implement filter interface
2. Mark the class as configuration class using @Configuration
3. Order of filer chain can be set @Oder(orderNo) if multiple filter exists
4. Implement doFilter method
5. Check Http Header value username/password/authentication code etc.
6. Return error if Authentication information is not correct

example:

`import java.io.IOException;`

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(1)
public class ReqResFilter implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            
    if(!req.getHeader("Authorization").equals("12345666")) {
        res.sendError(401, "Invalid Authorization code");
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

}